# jquery flot multi axes chart turning on and off check box

Tags: jquery, flot, legend

I have plotted jquery chart using flot. I have a legend with a checkbox that turns on and off. My plot has two yaxes. When I uncheck one or more box the right yaxis disappears. Does anyone has encountered this problem before? I have seen a similar question [jQuery Flot multi axes multi bar chart with on off legend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14593939/jquery-flot-multi-axes-multi-bar-chart-with-on-off-legend) the answer was not clear enough for me. 
Any tip is very much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you create a fiddle with the issue you are having?

Comment: It would be helpful to show some example data and the options you are passing to flot, along with your code for the checkboxes.